# return the path of an image that is hosted on my server to show it on the fron-end

Tags: node.js

currently on my server I have under the path theses images:

```
/opt/myproject/assets/5259521.jpg
/opt/myproject/assets/5259522.jpg
/opt/myproject/assets/5259523.jpg
```

I am using nodejs to create my web services. I want to know what is the way to return the path of my images so that the front-end can show them in an `img` tag.

my restAPI can be accessed by a path:

http://3.89.xx.xx/getImages

Here I would need to return the image paths so that I can display them in my web application.

```
    app.use(cors());
    app.options('*', cors());
    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

    // parse application/json
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // Configuración global de rutas
    app.use(require('./routes/index'));

    const distDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '/public');

    app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
        const file_path = path.join(distDirectory, req.url.split('?').shift());
        if (fs.existsSync(file_path)) next();
        else res.sendFile(path.join(distDirectory, 'index.html'));
    });
    app.use(express.static(distDirectory));
```

thanks

Comment: you can serve the files statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve static files such as images, CSS files, and JavaScript files, use the express.static built-in middleware function in Express.

The function signature is:

```
express.static(root, [options])
```

You need to put all you images in `public` folder or add the folder  name of you choice and then pass the static folder in the `express.static` middleware.

The name of the folder `Public`  is just a convention, you can set name of folder to anything.

For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

And access it like :

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/5259521.jpg
```

I am assuming that you  the images are under `public/assets` folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211527/discussion-between-sohail-and-yavg).

Comment: can you help me with this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257230/how-to-redirect-my-domain-to-localhost-3000-using-ngnix/61258355#61258355

Answer (score 0):

To use the static files in Node js

There is a path called 'public' which holds all the files CSS, Bootstrap, Images etc.

add this line to the code

```
app.use(express.static("public")
```

if the structure of public folder is

-public
   -css
   -picture
   -images

then you have use images for frontend

```
<img src = "picture/a.png">
<img src = "image/b.png">
<img src = "image/c.png">
```

you can have many folders in public folder