# how to redirect my domain to localhost: 3000 using ngnix

Tags: nginx

I'm new to all of this.

I'm going to put you in context. I bought a domain `miweb.pe` and an instance in aws. Currently my domain redirects to my aws instance because I have registered the dns servers of my amazon instance in `myweb.pe`.

I bought an ssl certificate and am trying to install it on my amazon instance, where I also installed `nginx`. I am unable to make any request to `myweb.pe` redirect to the aws instance that currently has a nodejs service active under port 3000.

this is my current configuration. What am I doing wrong?

```
    server {
            listen 443;
            server_name myweb.pe;
            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/beekey.key;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
    server {
            listen 80;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name www.myweb.pe;
            return 301 https://myweb.pe$request_uri;
    }

    # Redirige de https://www.tudominio.com a https://tudominio.com
    server {
            listen 443;
            server_name www.miweb.pe;
            return 301 $scheme://myweb.pe$request_uri;
    }
```

[image]

in summary, I want that when accessing `myweb.pe` it actually accesses the`localhost: 3000` which is running on my amazon instance.

Answer (score 0):

So, what is the issue you are facing, I can see one issue in your nginx rule for **servername** you need to type domain name and not localhost. The other thing is I am assuming your service on port 3000 should already be running.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it does not redirect me to my website. I am editing the / etc / nginx / sites-enabled / default file

Comment: my nodejs application is running on port 3000 with pm2 help

Comment: I add more details